# Git beginners: How can I remove a git history and git data?

Tags: git, github, directory, repository

How can I delete myentire git history and any other git data from my directory?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, or what you mean by "turn off my github".  Do you want to remove your local Git history, keep it and disconnect from github.com, or something else? (I presume you're aware that "github" refers specifically to the github.com web site, not to the Git software package.)

Comment: @KeithThompson the idea was delete my entire git history. It was already answered below. 
Thank you for your help too!

Comment: How does GitHub enter into it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want the directory to be a Git repository anymore just do:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Note that this will **delete your entire Git history** and any other Git data.

The files in the directory won't be affected, though.

Comment: It also won't affect any github repositories that this repo might be related to.